# HTML Table Data width won't stay static

Tags: html, css

No matter how I try, I cannot get all of these 'cells' to be 16px in width.
[HTML Table consisting of numbers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YjbiS.png)

Somethings keeps changing cells 1-9 to 8px regardless of what I do.

I am trying to generate a table of several rows that contain numbers from 1 to 100. I want all of the cells to be 16px in width, regardless of what value is in the cell.

I can't seem to figure out how to override the user-agent-stylesheet (which I think may be overriding my CSS).

Any help is much appreciated.

```css
td {
    border: 2px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: medium;
    border-color: aqua;
    width: 16px !important;
    overflow: hidden;
}

tr{
    border: 2px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: medium;
    border-color: aqua;
}

table {
    border: 2px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: medium;
    border-color: aqua; 
    color: crimson;
    background-color: black;
    table-layout: fixed;
    box-sizing: content-box;
    
}
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/test_style.css">
        <title>{{ title }} - My Test Site</title>
    </head>
    <body>
       <table>
            <tr>
                {% for data in table %}
                <td width="16px">{{ data.info }}</td>
                {% endfor %}
            </tr>
            <tr>
                {% for data in table %}
                <td width="16px">{{ data.info }}</td>
                {% endfor %}
            </tr>
            <tr>
                {% for data in table %}
                <td width="16px">{{ data.info }}</td>
                {% endfor %}
            </tr>
            <tr>
                {% for data in table %}
                <td width="16px">{{ data.info }}</td>
                {% endfor %}
            </tr>
       </table>

    </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Using the developer tools of your browser, you can check the cells and see what css affects it. That way you could find, what changes the cells.

Comment: Geshode, thanks. I have been in there already for hours. Like I said, no matter what I try nothing seems to work. Appreciate the advice though, I only stumbled on to the Inspect option in Chrome recently.

Comment: Ok, I figured it for my use case by setting the 'min-width' property of 'td' in the stylesheet to 16px. 
I suppose that should have come to me earlier, but I honestly didn't know it existed.